# Derived distribution of a function of two random variables

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to derive the following problem by myself from Bertsekas "Introduction to probability"
I cannot get the CDF of the 2nd interval (Z < 1) correctly. please identify my error.

[image]

**Please help to point out any wrong steps below!**

The general procedure is to first find the CDF of z, $F(z)$ and then differentiate to find the PDF.

The relationship is $Z = \frac{Y}{X}$ for $ 0 \leq X \leq 1 $ and $ 0 \leq Y \leq 1 $

The 3d plot is shown below for visualization. The line $Y = X$ seperates $Z < 1$ and $Z > 1$
[image]

The range of values of $Z$ can be split into the two intervals as shown below.

Let's find the CDF for the different intervals of $Z$.

From my understanding we try to find the CDF of Z for a particular interval through the CDF of Y and CDF of X over certain intervals in Y and X.

**1st Interval**
$ 0\leq Z \leq 1$ when $Y \leq X$

[image]

First let's try to find the CDF of Y

$F(z) = P(\frac{Y}{X} \leq z) = P(Y \leq ZX) $

PDF of Y is uniform over interval [0,1] therefore

$P(Y \leq ZX) = \int_{0}^{zx} 1 dy = zx$

Now the CDF of Y is a function of X so we can integrate out the X to find F(z) only in terms of z.

$F(z) = \int_{0}^{1} zx dx = \frac{z}{2}$

**2nd Interval**
$Z > 1$ when $Y > X$

This is the tricky one and I don't understand how to find it.

First we note that Y and X are strictly between [0,1]

Therefore to satisfy $ Y = ZX$ for the interval $Z > 1$.  $X$ can only vary from $0$ to $\frac{1}{Z}$

$F(z) = P(Y \leq ZX) = \int_{0}^{zx} 1 dy =  zx$

similarly as before we integrate out the x by $ F(z) = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{z}} zx dx = \frac{1}{2z}$

But why the CDF in the answer $1 - \frac{1}{2z}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of a misunderstanding here.  Suppose $z > 1$.  We want $\Pr[Y \le zX]$ but if $zX > 1$, this probability is $1$ and must be included.  If you wrote $$\Pr[Y \le zX] = \int_{x=0}^{1/z} \int_{y=0}^{zx} 1 \, dy \, dx,$$ you are missing this piece.  The full expression should be $$\Pr[Y \le zX] = \int_{x=0}^{1/z} \int_{y=0}^{zx} 1 \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=1/z}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 1 \, dy \, dx.$$
To make it a bit clearer, the joint density is simply $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 ,& 0 \le x , y \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$  If we want $\Pr[Y/X \le z]$ when $z > 1$, this corresponds to the trapezoidal region with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1/z, 1)$.  To see why, plot the line $Y = zX$ where $z > 1$ is the slope of the line.  This line passes through the origin and because it has slope greater than $1$, must also pass through the top edge of the unit square; specifically, it does so when $Y = 1$, so $X = 1/z$.  Then the inequality $Y/X \le z$ is satisfied for points in the square that are below this line.

Since this region is trapezoidal, we now see that if we are to integrate first with respect to $y$, we must divide the region into two subregions:  a triangular one from $x = 0$ to $x = 1/z$ with $y = 0$ to $zx$, and a rectangular one from $x = 1/z$ to $1$ and $y = 0$ to $1$.  This is precisely the integral we set up above.

However, we can save ourselves some trouble by changing the order of integration.  If we integrate with respect to $x$ first, then $$\Pr[Y \le zX] = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y/z}^1 1 \, dx \, dy = \int_{y=0}^1 1 - \frac{y}{z} \, dy = 1 - \frac{1}{2z}$$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @heropup for the very clear and detailed explaination. How did you come to the realization that the joint distribution is  $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}1 ,& 0 \le x , y \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$?

Is the joint PDF always the product of the marginal PDFs because X and Y are said to be independent random variables?

Does this mean that for multiple random variable probelms we always **need to know the joint distribution ** and then its a matter of finding the right region of integration for differnt intervals of $Z$? 

Again Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @PcumP_Ravenclaw When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint density is the product of the marginal densities.  We don't always have this luxury, however, so in some cases it is necessary to consider conditional distributions; e.g., in hierarchical models.  Your own computations implicitly used the joint density; my only contribution was to explicitly state it.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks @heropup